# Combine two or more arrays with differnet formant in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

i have three arrays ( `$genneral , $step_1 , $step_2`) and i have combine this in a specific format

```
if (ISSET($_GET['step_1'])){
    $step_1 = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $_GET['step_1']
                );
}

if(ISSET($_GET['step_2'])){
    $all_data=explode(",",$_GET['step_2']);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($all_data); $i++){
        $step_2[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' =>$all_data[$i]
                    );
   }

}

$genneral  = array(
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
```

So from this three array i have to combine this three array in a specific format

`if $_GET['step_1']=red`

`if $_GET['step_2']=hard,soft`

Then resulting argument should be like this ,

```
 $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'red' ),
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array( 'hard' ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => array( 'soft' ),
                        ),
                ),
     )
);
```

Please help to solve this .  I know this is hard , but some one can give answer it will be very helpful .

> Please note some time `$_GET['step_2']` contain many strings like
>   `$_GET['step_2']=hard,soft,boiled, melt..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning three separate variables I will do directly:-

```
if(isset($_GET['step_1'])  && isset($_GET['step_2'])){

    $all_data=explode(",",$_GET['step_2']);

    $step_2['relation'] = 'OR';

    foreach ($all_data as $value){
        $step_2[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' =>$value
                    );
   }

    $args = array(
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $_GET['step_1']
                            ),
                            $step_2
                        );
            );

}

print_r($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

For achieving the described resulting array, I'd approach it like this:

```
if( isset($_GET['step_1']) )
{
    $step1 = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => [ $_GET['step_1'] ],
    ];
}

if( isset($_GET['step_2']) )
{
    $step2 = ['relation' => 'OR'];
    foreach(explode(',', $_GET['step_2']) as $search_term)
    {

        $step2[] = [
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => [ $search_term ]
        ];
    }
}

$tax_query = ['relation' => 'AND'];
if(isset($step1)){ $tax_query[] = $step1; }
if(isset($step2)){ $tax_query[] = $step2; }

$args = [
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
];
```